# setNdefPushMessageCallback parameters when called from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nfc, android-beam

I want to call `setNdefMessageCallback` in a fragment but I don't know the parameters that I have to pass to that function. I think that it should be the `getContext()` but it give me a compile error saying that the method `setNdefPushMessageCallback` can't be applied to those params.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    //procedure that checks is NFC is avaible
    checkNfc();

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getContext());
    nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(getActivity(),getActivity());
}
```

Comment: Please read the documentation. It explains the parameters it needs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html

Comment: Even reading the documentation, I don't understand what indicate the first and the second param

Answer (score 1):

The [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessageCallback(android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...)) is pretty clear on this. This is the method signature:

```
void setNdefPushMessageCallback (NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback callback, 
                                 Activity activity, 
                                 Activity... activities)
```

The first parameter (`callback`) is an instance of a class that implements the `CreateNdefMessageCallback` interface. This is the object that should receive the callback in which you can assemble the NDEF message that should be pushed. Since you call the method `setNdefPushMessageCallback()` from a fragment, you would typically either use the fragment itself (i.e. you pass `this` and add an implements clause to your fragement declaration), or another object that you can control from your fragment.

The second parameter (or futher parameters) are *activities* for which you want to enable the NDEF message push callback. This would typically be the activity in which your fragment is loaded (`this.getActivity()`).

Hence, you could do something like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        ...

        nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, getActivity());

    }

    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        // TODO: assemble an NDEF message

        return ndefMessage;
    }
```